# Change Magento Header Logo to link to an external site in a multiple store account

Tags: multistore

I have multiple magento stores set up. I need to change only one of the stores' header logo to link to an external website. How do I do that?

I know where the header is:

app/design/frontend/default/[YOUR TEMPLATE]/template/page/html/header.phtml

and I know link is in this strip:

```
<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
        <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
        <?php else:?>
```

If I change it here, it will change all of the logos on the other stores as well. I only want to change the logo link of one store specifically.

Answer (score 4):

The short and ugly version is to hard code the id of the website and make an `if` statement in the template.

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId() == 4) : ?>
    Special logo and link here
<?php else : ?>
    Default behavior here
<?php endif;?>
```

The long an clean version is to add a configuration flag with scope website (or store view) and if that is set to 'yes' then display the custom logo and link.
Add something like this in `system.xml`

```
<config>
    <sections>
        ...
            <web>
                 <groups>
                     <custom_header translate="label">
                         <label>Custom header</label>
                         <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                         <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                         <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                         <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                         <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                         <fields> 
                             <custom_link translate="label">
                                 <label>Use custom header link</label>
                                 <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                 <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                                 <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                 <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                 <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                 <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                             </custom_link>
                         </fields>
                     </custom_header>
                 </groups>
             </web>
            ....
    </sections>
</config>
```

If you add it like this you should find your flag in the `Web` tab from `System->Configuration`.
Now you can add this in your template:

```
<?php if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('web/custom_header/custom_link')) : ?>
    Special logo and link here
<?php else : ?>
    Default behavior here
<?php endif;?>
```

And you can choose from the configuration panel which store has the custom link and logo.